# Representation of particular conditions within analytic tableaux

Tags: tables, math-mode, trees

I'm trying to represent some special conditions (see the attached image) in a document. I've tried to do it with bussproofs package and also with proftree[Tableau option] without success. No references found in the documentation. Can someone help me on how to do it?
Thanks[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: The first image is a very simple tree which could be done trivially with `forest`. The second is best done with a simple `tabular`.

Comment: You could do the first with `prooftrees`, but I don't see why anybody would. Plain `forest` would more than suffice. Not sure why you claim none of the packages' documentation includes any 'references'. They both show you how to do relevantly similar things.